# Php Download file to read from different Folders

Tags: php

I'm using Zubarg Smart File Download , to force my users to download audio files using :

```
download.php?f=FileName
```

i want this download.php to read mp3 files from different folders which are defined in :

```
define('BASE_DIR','downloads/');
```

how can i add more than one directories above to read from ??

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you can't... or you have to change the source code yourself.

Comment: Well, what does the documentation of that module you mention say?

Answer (score 0):

this is the code you need.

```
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer;");
       header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment, filename="' . $temp['file'] . $temp['fileext'].'";');  

header("Content-Length: ".filesize(BASE_DIR.$temp['file']));
readfile(BASE_DIR.$temp['file']);
```